# How can I convert 0.5 months and 1.5 months to 2 weeks and 6 weeks respectively using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How can I convert 0.5 months and 1.5 months to 2 weeks and 6 weeks respectively using moment.js?

I am consuming an API which has some object properties in units of months and I want to show fractional months in weeks where as keep the full numbers in months. Is this achievable using moment.js duration()?

Comment: Please show us some of your code to provide some context.  How are you storing these values?

Comment: Logically, add 0.5 months to a date, then get the difference in weeks.

Comment: If you are using 1 month == 4 weeks then just multiply by 4.

Comment: Just multiple the initial value by 4.  `0.5 x 4`-> 2, and `1.5 x 4` -> 6.  What issue are you running into?

Comment: Keep in mind that .5 months isn't exactly 2 weeks, nor is 6 weeks exactly 1.5, so moment.js may not be the right tool to use. The other suggestions of using 4 * .05 and 4 * 1.5 would work better, assuming you want to use four weeks as your basis for one month.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to solve this using moment's `duration`.

```
moment.duration({'months' : 0.5}).asWeeks();
```

Keep in mind that you'll have to round the output as you see fit, as in the above example the output will be 2.142857142857143.

This is how I'd approach this using moment.js but whether this is really what you're looking for is another question.

Documentation for moment.js durations [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/)

Answer (score 0):

The other answer appears to be much better, but logically this is how I tried to tackle the problem:

```js
var d = moment.duration(0.5, 'months')
var start = moment('01-01-2020')
var end = moment('01-01-2020').add(d.asSeconds(), 'seconds')
var now = end.diff(start, "week")

console.log(now) // 2
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```